# Can I call setupSpec() in cleanupSpec() in Spock

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock

In **setupSpec**() I have a lot of code to clean and populate myDB with spcific data. And I want to clean and repopulate it with the same data as in the beginning, after the execution of the tests in the suit, so in the **cleanupSpec**  I want to call **setupSpec**().

```
def cleanupSpec(){
   setupSpec()
}
```

but after this my *DB* is not in default state. So how to do it in right way?

Comment: *In setupSpec() I have a lot of code to clean myDB* - Why? Shouldn't it belong in `cleanup()` and/or `cleanupSpec()` directly

Comment: Ok not only clean but clean and populate specific data. I will edit it.

Comment: Then move the cleaning part to a private method which can be invoked both from `setupSpec()` and `cleanupSpec()`.

Comment: I have to clean at the end only in this test case(exceptional situation), so I do not want to refactor the code which is used in other 1000 test clasess,so I want just to call setupSpec() is it possible?

Comment: setupSpec() and cleanupSpec() is invoked before and after the execution of all features respectively and is applicable to available features. So I do not understand how they are applicable to one feature in particular. I may be misunderstanding it. If you share a sample `Specification` it would be easy to apprehend what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I do not want to show concrete example because you will give me ideas what to do and what not to do. I just ask is it possible to do that?

Comment: Basically it seems possible, however I don't find it as a good practice and it might cause a lot of errors and misunderstandings.

Comment: I found it. I must call super.setupSpec(),because my test case extends another. That why with only setupSpec() nothing happend.

Comment: @Xelian you should add an answer on your own and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I found it. I must call `super.setupSpec()`,because my test case extends another. That why with only `setupSpec`() nothing happend

Comment: is it working as when I tried I got error something like do not need to put super keyword explicitly that is already handled by framework.